# Protractor 3.1.1 + Angular2: Could not find testability for element

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I am running a simple HelloWorld sample with Protractor 3.1.1 and Angular2, but this thing keeps telling me **Could not find testability for element**. I googled the Internet for some information about the error, but no luck, it seems to be a new sort of exception that not so many have faced.

This is the component I'm using:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>' +
    '<h2>{{myName}}</h2>' +
    '<input id="someId" [(ngModel)]="myName"/>'
})
export class AppComponent {
    myName = 'Joe';
}
```

This is the Protractor config file:

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: [
    'e2e/*.js'
  ],
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
};
```

And this is the Protractor scenario I am running:

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
    it('should say my name', function() {
        browser.get('/index.html');
        var greeting = element(by.id('someId'));
        expect(greeting.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('Joe');
    });
});
```

The webpage loads normally with the template HTML rendered, but Protractor thinks the resulting webpage is not an Angular webpage, now, why is that? And obviously, if I inspect the resulting webpage, it is only the resulting HTML of the processed Angular code, am I doing something wrong?

This is the complete error:

```
Error: Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "Could not find testability for element."
```

If I run a simple test as the Protractor Tutorial says, using this demo page: http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/, it works as expected, so something has my Angular2 code that the Protractor is not working with it, but I already ran out of ideas, any one knows what is happening?

**UPDATE 23-02-2016**

After some research I found that to use Protractor with Angular2, there must be an additional configuration line in the config file:

```
useAllAngular2AppRoots: true
```

such that conf.js now looks like:

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: [
    'e2e/*.js'
  ],
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true
};
```

or include the app root explicitly with:

```
rootElement: 'my-app'
```

After this update all calls to find an element `by.id()` work OK, but if you pretend to use any of the locators `by.model()` or `by.binding()`, it will simply fail with the message `UnknownError: unknown error: angular is not defined`. No idea why.

Comment: same problem, I guess I'll use `by.id()` or `by.css()` for the moment...

Comment: You just saved me a lot of hassle buddy!

Comment: fixed it for me too! you should post the update as answer so others can easily find what the solution is.

Comment: Your update solved it for me. Please, arrange it as the answer, so that people could credit you.

Comment: Thanks for the UPDATE.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is a bug in that commit.
[Check this!](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3009).

But for now you can run your tests using 
`browser.executeScript('window.name = "NG_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO!"');`

Answer (score 0):

With Protractor and Angular, add `rootElement: 'my-app-root'` in your `protractor.conf.js` where `my-app-root` is the element name (CSS selector). Configuration documentation available [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/cc501f71bc1f995a83c1041e1aa489ea0f105679/lib/config.ts#L434).